# django add object with the current user

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to create a todoapp with google login to create personal todolist for each users.

here's **views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def todoView(request):
  all_todo_items = Todoitem.objects.filter(userid=request.user.id)
  return render(request, 'todoapp/home.html', {'all_items': all_todo_items})

def addTodo(request):
  add_new_item = Todoitem(content=request.POST['content'])
  add_new_item.save()
  return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
```

this is my code before without users but when there's currently login user it's throwing this error

**null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint / DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, sampletodo,null).** I believe the third column which is null is the userid and first column null is auto increment id since I set it to **id SERIAL primary key** in todoitem table

I'm 100% sure i need to add something **@addTodo views.py**, I just dont know how to add todolist with the current user

**EDIT here's my models.py**

```
class Todoitem(models.Model):
  content = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  userid = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING, 
  db_column='userid')

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'todoitem'

class AuthUser(models.Model):
password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
is_superuser = models.BooleanField()
username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
soon...

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'auth_user'
```

Comment: Can you share `TodoItem` model?

Comment: i edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the current user the same way you did in `todoView`. The `request` object has a reference to the current user through `request.user`. But you need to specify the `user` object, not `user.id`

```py
@login_required
def todoView(request):
  all_todo_items = Todoitem.objects.filter(userid=request.user)  # changed to request.user
  return render(request, 'todoapp/home.html', {'all_items': all_todo_items})

def addTodo(request):
  add_new_item = Todoitem(content=request.POST['content'], userid=request.user)
  add_new_item.save()
  return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
```

Comment: i get an error when i use filter(userid=request.user) Cannot query "username": Must be "AuthUser" instance. is id not user object?

Comment: its displaying my todoitems with the current user using filter(userid=request.user.id)

Comment: @JackClarkson yea, my fault, did not see that you used `db_column`, then you need to use `request.user.id`

Comment: for my addTodo do i need to use add_new_item = Todoitem(content=request.POST['content'], userid=request.user.id) ? because i get this error Cannot assign "2": "Todoitem.userid" must be a "AuthUser" instance

Comment: is `AuthUser` related to your `User` model? if so, you can retrieve the `AuthUser` instance and set it to `TodoItem`

Comment: the class AccountEmailaddress(models.Model): user = models.ForeignKey('AuthUser', models.DO_NOTHING) i guess this one is related, tbh im new to this and  i just follow this tutorial https://whizzoe.medium.com/in-5-mins-set-up-google-login-to-sign-up-users-on-django-e71d5c38f5d5

Comment: there's no user model

Answer (score 0):

You should use a good user model to be able to use **`request.user`**.

Try a model like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField()
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
```

then in your views you can do this

```
def addTodo(request):
  add_new_item = Todoitem(content=request.POST['content'], userid=request.user)


def todoView(request):
  all_todo_items = Todoitem.objects.filter(userid=request.user)  # changed to request.user
  return render(request, 'todoapp/home.html', {'all_items': all_todo_items})
```